# How to make header full screen on scroll?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have `data-fullscreen="true"` on my fixed header for a jQuery Mobile app. It's "see-thru" on top of my content, so I am hoping I can turn it solid on the page load, then see-thru when the user starts scrolling (or solid only when scrolled to the top).

Comment: What do you mean by page load? Loading contents into active page? Or during pages transition?

Comment: What is your exact question? Do you want to change the opacity of your header while scrolling?

Comment: I have a link to page2.html that loads via ajax. The header shows on top of the content so it is covered at the top. I want to make the header just data-position="fixed" when looking at the page, but as soon as the scroll happens, to make the header data-fullscreen="true" from that point on.